# Need help changing the color of a selected button

Tags: css

The code in my stylesheet I used to change the color of a selected button isn't working. The hover function works but it won't keep the color after being selected.

My code is below. I don't know enough about CSS to really troubleshoot all that much.

```css
body .btn:hover,
body .MS_contentWrapper_inner .PaymentPartSubmitButton:hover,
body .MS_contentWrapper_inner [id*='AddProgramDailyAdmissionToCart']:hover,
input[type="submit"]:hover,
.BBFormSubmitButton:hover,
#anchorOtherDates:hover,
#anchorOtherTimes:hover,
.Programming_Event_AlternateDatesCaption:hover,
.Programming_Event_AlternateTimesCaption:hover {
  background: #E77229 !important;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none !important;
}

body .btn:active,
body .MS_contentWrapper_inner .PaymentPartSubmitButton:active,
body .MS_contentWrapper_inner [id='AddProgramDailyAdmissionToCart']:active,
input[type="submit"]:active,
.BBFormSubmitButton:active,
#anchorOtherDates:active,
#anchorOtherTimes:active,
.Programming_Event_AlternateDatesCaption:active,
.Programming_Event_AlternateTimesCaption:active {
  background: #E77229 !important;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none !important;
}
```

The top half of the code works great but the second half changes nothing.

Comment: I think the html code is missing, to really be helpfull to you :)

Comment: from [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active)  The :active CSS pseudo-class represents an element (such as a button) that is being activated by the user. When using a mouse, "activation" typically starts when the user presses down the primary mouse button.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need the color to stay after you clicked the button you need to set the style dynamically on click. I suggest using a css class for this which you can use to set any style you want.

Example:

HTML:

```
<input type="submit">
```

CSS:

```
.active {
  background-color: deeppink;
  color: white;
  border: none;
}
```

JS:

```
document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.target.classList.add('active');
  });
```